# Early execution of "sp_rename" causes query to fail

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having a strange problem with an MSSQL Query that I'm trying to run in Microsoft SQL Server 2014. It is an update script for my database structure. It should basically rename a Column (from `Price` to `SellingPrice`) of a Table **after** its content was merged to another one.

```
USE db_meta
GO

DECLARE @BakItemPrices TABLE
(
    ItemNum int,
    Price int,
    CashPrice int
)

-- backup old prices
insert into @BakItemPrices
select ItemNum, Price from dbo.ItemInfo

-- merge into other table
alter table ShopInfo
add column Price int NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0))

update ShopInfo
set ShopInfo.Price = i.Price
from ShopInfo s
inner join @BakItemPrices i
on s.ItemNum = i.ItemNum

GO

-- rename the column
exec sp_rename 'ItemInfo.Price', 'SellingPrice', 'COLUMN'  -- The Debugger executes this first
GO
```

This query always gave me the error

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
>   Invalid column name 'Price'.

I couldn't understand this error until I debugged the query. I was amazed as I saw that the debugger wont even hit the breakpoint I placed at the backup code and says that "its unreachable because another batch is being executed at the moment".

Looking further down I saw that the debugger instantly starts with the `exec sp_rename ...` line before it executes the query code that I wrote above. So at the point my backup code is being executed the Column is named `SellingPrice` and not `Price` which obviously causes it to fail.

I thought queries get processed from top to bottom? Why is the execute sequence being executed before the code that I wrote above?

Comment: Why don't you simply add the column with the name SellingPrice in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Script is sequenced from top to down. But some changes to schema is "visible" after the transaction with script is committed. Split your script into two scripts, it can help.